# SQL group by and max and other fields

Tags: sql, group-by, max

I have a table that contains:

```
ITEMID COSTAMOUNTPOSTED QTY DATEPHYSICAL
10001       20          20   2014-10-01
10001       30          20   2014-10-20
10005       20          20   2014-10-01
10005       20          30   2014-10-15
```

I want to select the last physical action with the item, the result I want to get is:

```
ITEMID COSTAMOUNTPOSTED QTY DATEPHYSICAL
10001       30          20   2014-10-20
10005       20          30   2014-10-15
```

The query I run :

```
SELECT itemid,costamountposted,qty,datephysical
  FROM A 
  where datephysical =(select max(datephysical) 
  FROM A
```

But I only get result with items that have biggest physical date. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this using subquery,

```
SELECT a.*
FROM tableName a 
     INNER JOIN
     (
        SELECT ITEMID , MAX(DATEPHYSICAL) max_date
        FROM tableName 
        GROUP BY ITEMID 
     ) b ON a.ITEMID  = b.ITEMID AND a.DATEPHYSICAL = b.max_date
```